# spectral decomposition of a bivariate function

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Now I have a function $f=f(x,y)$, smooth and symmetric(i.e. $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ everywhere), with arguments defined on a compact set: $(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

I'd wish to know if $f$ can be expanded as $f(x, y) = \sum_{l=1}^\infty \lambda_l \xi_l(x)\xi_l(y)$, where $\xi_l(\cdot)$ are functions that are norm 1 and orthogonal to each other -- here I define the needed inner product between two functions $u, v$ on $[0,1]$ to be $<u, v> := \int_0^1 u(t)v(t)dt$.

A reasonably easy to follow reference will be good enough for my question. Just I didn't know what the correct key words to use -- I tried "functional spectral theory" etc and got something too abstract for me to understand(and they were unnecessarily general for my purpose of application). Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I just come across your question. Perhaps the paper by Courant and Hilbert (1953) can answer your question. Bounded, symmetric and positive definite guarantees the ability to decompose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, assume $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ is a real function. Because $f$ is in $L^{2}([0,1]\times[0,1])$, then the integral operator $K$ given by
$$
          Kg = \int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)g(y)\,dy
$$
is a selfadjoint **Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator** on $L^{2}[0,1]$. So there is an orthonormal basis $\{\varphi_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ consisting of real eigenfunctions of $K$ with corresponding real eigenvalues of $K$. The eigenfunctions with non-zero eigenvalues are smooth because they inherit smoothness from $k$:
$$
             \varphi_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda_{n}}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)\varphi_{n}(y)\,dy.
$$
To show that $\{ \varphi_{n}(x)\varphi_{m}(y)\}_{n,m=1}^{\infty,\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^{2}([0,1]\times[0,1])$, notice that this set is an orthonormal subset of $L^{2}([0,1]\times[0,1])$, and Parseval's equality for $L^{2}[0,1]$ gives Parseval's equality for every $g \in L^{2}([0,1]\times[0,1])$:
$$
\begin{align}
    &\sum_{n,m}\left|\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}g(x,y)\varphi_{n}(x)\varphi_{n}(y)\,dx\,dy\right|^{2} \\
   & = \sum_{n}\sum_{m}\left|\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}g(x,y)\varphi_{n}(x)\,dx\right)\varphi_{m}(y)\,dy\right|^{2} \\
   & = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n}\left|\int_{0}^{1}g(x,y)\varphi_{n}(x)\,dx\right|^{2}\,dy \\
   & = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}|g(x,y)|^{2}\,dx\,dy.
\end{align}
$$
So, the following sum converges in $L^{2}([0,1]\times[0,1])$:
$$
\begin{align}
        K(x,y) = \sum_{n,m}\left[\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)\varphi_{n}(y)\varphi_{m}(x)\,dydx\right]\varphi_{n}(x)\varphi_{m}(y)
\end{align}
$$
Because $\varphi_{n}$ is an eigenfunction of $K$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_{n}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
  K(x,y)
    & = \sum_{n,m}\left[\int_{0}^{1}\left[\int_{0}^{1}k(x,y)\varphi_{n}(y)\,dy\right]\varphi_{m}(x)\,dx\right]\varphi_{n}(x)\varphi_{m}(y) \\
    & = \sum_{n,m}\left[\lambda_{n}\int_{0}^{1}\varphi_{n}(x)\varphi_{m}(x)\,dx\right]\varphi_{n}(x)\varphi_{m}(y) \\
    & = \sum_{n}\lambda_{n}\varphi_{n}(x)\varphi_{n}(y).
\end{align}
$$
All functions $\varphi_{n}$ in the final sum are smooth because $0$ eigenvalue terms drop out. The convergence of the sum is in $L^{2}([0,1]\times[0,1])$.

Comment: I don't understand the justification for the transition $\sum_{n}\sum_{m}\cdots = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n}\cdots$ in the first equality chain.

Comment: @EvanAad : This is a repeated application of Parseval's equality for the orthonormal basis $\{ \varphi_{n}\}$ on $L^{2}[0,1]$, starting with an application to the function $h_{n}(y)=\int_{0}^{1}g(x,y)\varphi_{n}(x)\,dx$

Comment: Parseval's identity says that if $(e_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space $H$ (defined over the field $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$), and if $a_1, a_2, \dots \in \mathbb{K}$ are such that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty |a_n|^2 < \infty$, then $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n e_n$ converges and $\|\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n e_n\|^2 = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty |a_n|^2$.

Comment: In the present case, $(\varphi_m)_{m = 1}^\infty$ is the orthonormal basis. What about the $a_n$'s? Are you saying that the $h_n$'s play the role of the $a_n$'s? But this is impossible, because the $h_n$'s are functions, whereas the $a_n$'s ought to be scalars $\in \mathbb{K}$.

Comment: @EvanAad : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|(h,\varphi_{n})|^{2}=\|h\|^{2}$. And $(h,\varphi_{n})=\int_{0}^{1}h(y)\varphi_{n}(y)\,dy$.