# Exercise 34 from chapter 4 ("Hilbert Spaces: An Introduction") of Stein & Shakarchi's "Real Analysis"

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider exercise 34 from chapter 4 ("Hilbert Spaces: An Introduction") of [1] (p. 201):

> Let K be a Hilbert-Schmidt kernel which is real and symmetric. Then, as we saw, the operator $T$ whose kernel is $K$ is compact and symmetric. Let $\{\varphi_k(x)\}$ be the eigenvectors (with eigenvalues $\lambda_k$) that diagonalize $T$. Then:
>
> (a) $\sum_k |\lambda_k|^2 < \infty$
>
> (b) $K(x,y) \sim \sum\lambda_k\varphi_k(x)\varphi_k(y)$ is the expansion of $K$ in the basis $\{\varphi_k(x)\varphi_k(y)\}$.
>
> (c) Suppose $T$ is a compact operator which is symmetric. Then $T$ is of Hilbert-Schmidt type if and only if $\sum_n |\lambda_n|^2 < \infty$, where $\{\lambda_n\}$ are the eigenvalues of $T$ counted according to their multiplicities.

I'd appreciate help in solving parts (b) and (c) (I have figured out part (a) on my own). For completeness, here's how [1] defines *a Hilbert-Schmidt kernel* (pp. 186-187). Note that $\mathcal{H}$ stands for a Hilbert space and that only separable Hilbert spaces are considered throughout [1].

> Let $\mathcal{H} = L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$. If we can define an operator $T:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ by the formula
>   $$
> T(f)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} K(x,y)f(y)\ dy,\hspace{1cm} \mbox{whenever } f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d),
> $$
>   we say that the operator $T$ is an ***integral operator*** and $K$ is its associated ***kernel***. [...] ***Hilbert-Schmidt operators*** [... are integral operators ...] with a kernel $K$ that belongs to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^d)$.

---

***References***

[1] Stein, Elias M. and Shakarchi, Rami. Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces. Princeton University Press (2005)

Comment: I posted a solution that had additional information about smoothness when $K$ is smooth, but all mention of smoothness can be skipped and the solution to what you want is there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918902/spectral-decomposition-of-a-bivariate-function/919067#919067

Comment: I was not aware that an almost identical post exists...T_T

Comment: @T.A.E.: Thank you. It's a very good answer for part (b). Could you please help me with part (c) too?

Comment: @Evan Aad : Square the expansion in (b) and integrate. Use the first equality string for $\|g\|$ in the post I referenced.

Comment: @Bombyxmori : Out of the 300,000+ answers on the site, you didn't find that? :) Don't worry, Evan Aad didn't notice that problem either. They're not identical problems, and I knew about the other one only because I spent too much time trying to put together a clean solution to the other problem.

Comment: @T.A.E.: But the post you referenced implicitly assumes that $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, whereas in part (c) here we need to show that $K \in L^2$.

Comment: @EvanAad : In part (c), assume $T$ is as stated with $\sum_{n}|\lambda_{n}|^{2} < \infty$ with orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions $\varphi_{n}$. Show that $Tf=\sum_{n}(Tf,\varphi_{n})\varphi_{n}=\sum_{n}\lambda_{n}(f,\varphi_{n})\varphi_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n}\lambda_{n}\varphi_{n}(x)\varphi_{n}(y)f(y)\,dy$ is Hilbert-Schmidt because $\{\varphi_{n}(x)\varphi_{n}(y)\}$ is an orthonormal subset of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d}\times\mathbb{R}^{d})$. The converse has been done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space as desired. For simplicity assuming we are working over the real field. Then being an integral operator, we have
$$
K: H\rightarrow H, (Kf)(x)=\int K(x,y)f(y)dy
$$
Since $K$ is a symmetric compact operator, it is normal and can be diagonalized. Let us write its eigenvectors as $\phi_{j}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_{j}$. Then we know $\phi_{j}$s span $H$. Thus $K$ can be defined alternatively by
$$
\forall f=\sum a_{j}\phi_{j}, (K(\sum a_{j}\phi_{j}))(x)=\sum a_j \lambda_{j}\phi_{j}(x)=\int_{H} \sum\lambda_{j} \phi_{j}(x)\phi_{j}(y)(\sum a_{i}\phi_{i}(y))dy
$$
where we normalized $\langle \phi_{i}, \phi_{j}\rangle=\delta_{ij}$. The equality holds because for each term we have
$$
a_{i}\lambda_{j}\phi_{j}(x)\int_{H}\phi_{j}(y)\phi_{i}(y)dy=a_{i}\lambda_{j}\phi_{j}(x)\delta_{ij}
$$
and this concludes the proof.

Comment: Thank you. Which part did you solve? (b) or (c)?

Comment: This is enough to prove (b) and (c).

Comment: I see why your answer proves part (b). However regarding part (c), I still don't see why $\sum |\lambda_k|^2 < \infty$ implies that $T$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator.

Comment: @EvanAad: In the case of (c), the only real thing left to do is to show $K$ is a Hilbert-Schimidt operator. The condition given guarantees its norm is finite.

Comment: So the condition $\sum|\lambda_k|^2 < \infty$ guarantees that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^d}|K(x,y)|^2 d(x,y) < \infty$? How?

Comment: Just use Fubini's theorem and check it yourself. Since you are reading Stein's book, this should not be difficult for you.

Comment: Another hint is T.A.E's answer in the other post already did it.

Comment: T.A.E.'s answer assumes that $f(x,y) \in L^2$ (i.e. that $f$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator), however we can't make the assumption that $K$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator in part (c), because this is exactly what needs to be shown. For the same reason, part (c) can't use part (b).

Comment: No, this is not true. You know $T$ is compact, symmetric, so you can write out $T$ in terms of the eigenvectors as a basis. Your job is just to find its Hilbert-Schmidt norm is bounded. But this is essentially given to you.

Comment: I agree that $T$ is bounded. For $T$ to be bounded you don't even need the condition $\sum |\lambda_k|^2 < \infty$: it suffices that $T$ is compact, since every compact linear transformation is bounded.

Comment: However, we are not asked to show that $T$ is bounded, but rather that $\int |K(x,y)|^2\, d(x,y) < \infty$. I think you are making the mistake of assuming that $\|T\|^2 = \int |K(x, y)|^2\,d(x,y)$. However, we don't know that this is the case. If we knew that $K \in L^2$, then this identity would in fact hold, since every Hilbert-Schmidt operator satisfies this identity; but we don't know that $K \in L^2$, indeed this is the very fact we are required to prove.

Comment: @EvanAad: The usual Hilbert-Schmidt norm is defined by $\sum |Ae_{i}|^{2}$. So this just follows from definition. Here in your case we are using Stein's definition(check page 187), and you need to show $K\in L^{2}(H\times H)$. I do not understand where did you get $\int_{H\times H} |K(x,y)|d(x,y)$ into the formula - everything is $L^{2}$ at here.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but I consider it as only solving part (b). I've given a separate answer for part (c). Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I am confused with your proof. You claim that the image of your map is complete, then you work with the completion of the image. It suffice to compute $T$'s $L^{2}$ norm directly by definition.

Comment: I'm sorry you're confused. If you find an error in my proof please let me know. If you are able to come up with a different proof, write it down and I'll be happy to read it.

Comment: I believe that since $\Psi(L^{2}(H\times H))$ is complete, its closure should be identical to itself since the map is an isometry. So the second part of your proof is not really needed.

Comment: You're absolutely correct: $\overline{\Psi(\cdots)} = \Psi(\cdots)$, which is why it is sufficient to find a sequence of members of $\Psi(\cdots)$ that converges to $T$ in order to show that $T$ itself belongs to $\Psi(\cdots)$ (note that $\Psi(\cdots)$ is precisely the set of Hilbert-Schmidt operators).

Comment: Since you agree that they are indeed the same, then to show $T$ belongs to $\Psi(L^{2}(H\times H)$ you just need to show its kernel belong to $L^{2}(H\times H)$, since the map is an isometry. And I think this has been given to you already.

Comment: If you take $T$ to be a Hilbert-Schmidt operator a-priori then part (c) makes no sense, since we have already proved one direction in part (a) and for the converse direction there is nothing at all to prove.

Comment: We do not know $T$ is Hilbert-Schmidt at here. But we do have a spectral decomposition of it. So once you establish its kernel in $L^{2}(H\times H)$, then $T$ must be Hilbert-Schmidt since $\Psi$ is an isometry.

Comment: Ah but how do you establish that its kernel is in $L^2(\cdots)$? One way is by the proof that I have given. You have not convinced me that any part of this proof is redundant. If you have another idea of how to prove that the kernel is in $L^2(\cdots)$, please write it down and I'll be happy to read it.

Comment: I will leave it for you to discover it. The fact that the kernel is in $L^{2}(H\times H)$ is trivial. This is your work, after all. I consider myself being patient enough to lead you until this point. I have to do my work now.

Comment: I should add that the kernel obtained non-constructively in the proof that I have given is not necessarily the same as the $K$ specified in the original question. It is not inconceivable that there are two different "kernels" that yield the same operator $T$. Of course, this cannot be if the two kernels are in $L^2$, but it is conceivable that one of them (the one obtained in my proof) will be in $L^2$ whereas the other one (the original $K$) will not be in $L^2$.

Comment: Sorry but I do not have time to respond any further. Please clear your confusion with your professor/advisor, who is more authoritative than I am to you. I have to do my TA work for students like you and cook a lunch for myself. See you.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a solution to part (c). One direction was proved in part (a). Therefore, I will only prove the other direction: assuming $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty |\lambda_n|^2 < \infty$, I will show that $T$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator (where $\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues corresponding to some orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, such that $T(f) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lambda_n \left<f, \varphi_n\right> \varphi_n$ for all $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$).

There is a natural isometry $\Psi$ from $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^d)$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, namely $\Psi(k) := T_k$, where
$$
T_k(f) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}k(x,y)f(y)\,dy
$$
Note that $\Psi(L^2(\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d))$ is precisely the set of Hilbert-Schmidt operators.

Now, let $T \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be compact and symmetric. Since $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^d)$ is complete and $\Psi$ is norm-preserving, $\Psi(L^2(\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d))$ is complete. It suffices, therefore, to show that $T \in \overline{\Psi(L^2(\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d))}$.

$T$ being compact and symmetric, by the spectral theorem there is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $\varphi_n \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, with $\lambda_n$ being the eigenvalue corresponding to $\varphi_n$, such that for every $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$,
$$
T(f) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lambda_n \left<f,\varphi_n\right>\varphi_n
$$
We suppose that $\sum_{n = 1}|\lambda_n|^2 < \infty$.

For every $N \in \mathbb{N}_1$, define
$$
T_N(f) := \sum_{n = 1}^N \lambda_n \left<f,\varphi_n\right>\varphi_n
$$
We have $T_N = \Psi(k_N)$ with
$$
k_N(x,y) := \sum_{n = 1}^N\lambda_n\phi_n(x)\overline{\phi_n(y)}
$$
(recall that $\{\phi_k(x)\overline{\phi_m(y)}\}_{k,m \in \mathbb{N}_1}$ form a basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d)$).

It remains to show: $\|T - T_N\| \underset{N \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$. Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with $\|f\| = 1$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|(T - T_n)(f)\|^2 & = \left\|\sum_{n = N+1}^\infty \lambda_n \left<f,\varphi_n\right>\varphi_n\right\|^2 \\
& = \sum_{n = N + 1}^\infty\left|\lambda_n
\right|^2\left|\left<f,\varphi_n\right>\right|^2 \\
& \leq \sum_{n = N + 1}^\infty \left|\lambda_n\right|^2 \left\|f\right\|^2\left|\varphi_n\right\|^2 \\
& = \sum_{n = N + 1} \left|\lambda_n\right|^2
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, since by assumption $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left|\lambda_n\right|^2 < \infty$, $\|T - T_N\| \underset{N \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$, Q.E.D.