# Hilbert-Schmidt Operator with Real & Symmetric Kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I'm currently solving the following exercise (in chapter 4  of Stein's Real Analysis / Measure Theory)

> **Exercise 34**
>
> Let K be a Hilbert-Schmidt kernel which is real and symmetric. Then, as we saw, the operator $T$ whose kernel is $K$ is compact and symmetric. Let $\{\varphi_k(x)\}$ be the eigenvectors (with eigenvalues $\lambda_k$) that diagonalize $T$. Then:
>
> (a) $\sum_k |\lambda_k|^2 < \infty$
>
> (b) $K(x,y) \sim \sum\lambda_k\varphi_k(x)\varphi_k(y)$ is the expansion of $K$ in the basis $\{\varphi_k(x)\varphi_k(y)\}$.
>
> (c) Suppose $T$ is a compact operator which is symmetric. Then $T$ is of Hilbert-Schmidt type if and only if $\sum_n |\lambda_n|^2 < \infty$, where $\{\lambda_n\}$ are the eigenvalues of $T$ counted according to their multiplicities.

Below are some questions about this exercise

---

**(a)**

By spectral thm, $\{\varphi_k\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathcal H = L^2(\mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^d)$.

Let $f = \sum_k \varphi_k \in \mathcal H$. Then, $T(f) = \sum_k T(\varphi_k) = \sum_k \lambda_k \varphi_k \in \mathcal H$. So,

$$\Vert Tf \Vert ^2 = \Vert \sum_k \lambda_k \varphi_k \Vert ^2 = \sum_k |\lambda_k|^2 \Vert \varphi_k \Vert ^2 = \sum_k |\lambda_k|^2$$

Since $Tf \in \mathcal H$, $\sum_k |\lambda_k|^2 < \infty$

<s>I'd like to check whether this is correct.</s>

I guess this method is totally wrong. What method should I use for $\sum_k |\lambda_k|^2 < \infty$?

---

**(b)**

I tried to solve this in the following way, which isn't sure.

Let $Tf(x) = \int_{\mathbb R ^d}K(x,y)f(y)dy$.

$T(\varphi_k(x)) = \int_{\mathbb R ^d}K(x,y)\varphi_k(y)dy = \lambda_k \varphi_k (x)$

$(T(\varphi_k(x)), \varphi_k(x)) = (\lambda_k \varphi_k (x), \varphi_k (x)) = \lambda_k\Vert \varphi_k(x)\Vert ^2 = \lambda_k$

Also, $(T(\varphi_k(x)), \varphi_k(x)) = \int_{\mathbb R ^d}\int_{\mathbb R ^d}K(x,y)\varphi_k(y)dy \overline{\varphi_k(x)} dx = \int_{\mathbb R ^{2d}}K(x,y)\overline{\varphi_k(x)} \varphi_k(y)d(x,y)$

So, $K(x,y) \sim \sum_k \lambda_k \overline{\varphi_k(x)} \varphi_k(y)$

...

I'd like to know whether there is a wrong point. The answer in the textbook has no conjugate form.

Also, the eigenvectors are estimated to be **REAL**, which I'm not sure about.  Some explanation about it would be grateful.

---

**(c)**

<s>I referred to this [page](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/934756/1118138) to understand this problem, and it says that $\Vert T - T_N \Vert \to 0$ implies that $T$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator. But I can't figure out what this means. I thought I have to find some $K$ where $Tf(x) = \int K(x,y)f(y)dy$  and $K \in L^2(\mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^d)$, which isn't clear in the page. Without showing the existence of such $K$, how could I finish this problem?</s>

---

Any help about this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$(a)$ Why would $f$ be in $\mathcal{H}$ ? in fact, you can be sure that $f$ never exists in $\mathcal{H}$ because
$$
\|f\| = \left\|\sum_{n \geqslant 0} \varphi_n\right\| = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} \|\varphi_n\| = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} 1 = +\infty.
$$
In fact, $T$ is assumed to be Hilbert-Schmidt which means by definition that $\sum_{n \geqslant 0} \|T\varphi_n\|^2 = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} \lambda_n^2 < +\infty$.

$(b)$ There is no conjugate form because all your functions are real. To prove that $K(x,y) = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} \lambda_n\varphi_n(x)\varphi_n(y)$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{2d})$, begin by proving that the sum $\tilde{K}(x,y) = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} \lambda_n\varphi_n(x)\varphi_n(y)$ converges in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{2d})$. For this, use point $(a)$, the fact that for all $n$, $(x,y) \mapsto \varphi_n(x)\varphi_n(y) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{2d})$ with $L^2$-norm equals $1$ and the Fubini-Tonelli theorem that allows you to exchange the sum and the integral.

Then, verify that for all $n$, $\tilde{T}\varphi_n = \lambda_n\varphi_n$ where $\tilde{T}$ is the Hilbert-Schmidt operator defined using $\tilde{K}$. Use it to deduce that $\tilde{T} = T$ hence $\tilde{K} = K$ a.e..

$(c)$ This is the same idea than for question $(b)$. If $\sum_{n \geqslant 0} \lambda_n^2 < +\infty$, then $K(x,y) = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} \lambda_n\varphi_n(x)\varphi_n(y)$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{2d})$. Then, define $\tilde{T}$ to be the operator with kernel $K$, prove that for all $n$, $\tilde{T}\varphi_n = \lambda_n\varphi_n$ and deduce that $T = \tilde{T}$ is a Hilbert_Schmidt operator.

Comment: thank you. I have additional questions about the reply. In (a), based on my calculation, the $f = \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n \varphi_k$ does not make $\Vert Tf \Vert$ equal to $\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k ^2$, rather  $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k ^2$. In (b), I'm not sure why the eigenvectors are all real. Finally, does the notation '~' mean 'equal a.e.'?

Comment: My bad, I mistook for the first part, I edited my post. And $\sim$ means that $K$ is the limit of the series $(x,y) \mapsto \sum \lambda_k\varphi_k(x)\varphi_k(y)$. It often, but not always, implies convergence a.e.. For example, if $f_n$ is the indicator function of $\left[\frac{n%2^m}{2^m},\frac{(n + 1)%2^m}{2^{m + 1}}\right]$ where $m$ is such that $2^m \leqslant n < 2^{m + 1}$ and $%$ is the reminder of the Euclidean division, then $f_n \rightarrow 0$ for the norm $L^2$ but we don't have a.e. convergence.

Comment: ok, i got it. Then, could you explain more about why all the eigenvectors are real? Is it related to the real function $K$?, or is it just from some definition?

Comment: There are real Hilbert spaces and complex Hilbert spaces. The fact that the conjugation doesn"t appear suggests that it is real (if it is complex, the formula is wrong and conjugations should appear). You can do the same exercice with complex valued functions. In this case, replace question $(b)$ by $K(x,y) \sim \sum_{n \geqslant 0} \lambda_k\varphi_k(x)\overline{\varphi_k(y)}$.