# Uniqueness of spectral decomposition of a bivariate complex-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I have a complex-valued function of two real variables - let's denote it $m(x,y)$. I am told that it should have a spectral decomposition of the form:
$$ m(x,y)=\sum_n\lambda_n\chi_n^*(x)\chi_n(y) $$
It is true that $m(x,y)=m(y,x)$. This is in a physics context, so 'nice' properties like continuity and differentiability can be assumed as necessary. On physics grounds, I am reasonably sure that the $\chi_n$ should be orthogonal to each other with respect to the usual inner product, and somewhat sure that we should have $\lambda_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

I want to know why such a decomposition should exist, and if it is unique. If it's not unique, are there any obvious further constraints that would enforce uniqueness?

I found a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918902/spectral-decomposition-of-a-bivariate-function), but that only dealt with a real-valued function and didn't mention uniqueness of the decomposition.

My relevant math background is limited to one course in real analysis and just enough complex analysis to calculate a contour integral, so further references would be handy!